# Merge Browser-Cache and Browser-Caching

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

I believe the tags [browser-cache](/questions/tagged/browser-cache)  and [browser-caching](/questions/tagged/browser-caching) should be merged into one with [browser-caching](/questions/tagged/browser-caching) being a synonym of [browser-cache](/questions/tagged/browser-cache).

Comment: I created a synonym: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/browser-cache/synonyms If 4 people vote for the synonym, then it'll be auto-merged.

Comment: I've retagged question, since you have 2k+ rep on SO, you can retag them too.